# Action in Scala/Spark is not getting executed after a transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am currently experimenting with Apache Spark through Scala. I am currently using version 2.4.3 of Spark Core (as defined in my build.sbt file). I am running a simple example: generating a RDD through a text file and filtering all the lines that contain the word "pandas". After that, I use an action to count the number of lines that actually contains that word in the file. If I simply try to count the total number of lines of the file, everything goes ok, but if I apply a filter transformation and then try to count the number of elements, it does not finish the execution.

```
    import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
    println("Creating Context")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val lines = sc.textFile("/home/lbali/example.txt")
    val pandas = lines filter(line => line.contains("pandas"))
    println("+++++ number of lines: " + lines.count()) // this works ok.
    println("+++++ number of lines with pandas: " + pandas.count()) // This does not work
    sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try persisting the dataframe. When multiple actions are performed over the same dataframe, it is better to persist it rather than going through the cycle again

```
lines.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Answer (score -1):

Think I found a solution, downgrading the Scala version from 2.12.8 to 2.11.12 solved the issue.